# Is there an equivalent of Bitcoin Script Opcodes or the EVM instruction set in Cardano

Tags: plutus, smart-contract

Is there some lower level code that Plutus code compiles to (akin to Solidity => EVM bytecode, or BSV sCrypt => OP_codes)?

Related (but distinct) how the state changes: https://cardano.stackexchange.com/a/7253/4968

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is a lower level code that is used onchain, it is called Untyped Plutus Core (UPLC)! When validators are written in template haskell, they get [compiled](https://iohk.io/en/blog/posts/2021/02/02/plutus-tx-compiling-haskell-into-plutus-core/) via

```
1) GHC: Haskell -> GHC Core
2) Plutus Tx compiler: GHC Core -> Plutus IR
3) Plutus IR compiler: Plutus IR -> Typed Plutus Core
4) Type eraser: Typed Plutus Core -> Untyped Plutus Core
```

To learn more about UPLC have a look at this great [blog](https://hachi.one/post/an-introduction-to-plutus-core/).